# Accessing a Struct as a Global Var in a .m file

Tags: c, struct, core-audio

I have a struct that contains pointers to values that must be used in several functions throughout my class.  I typedef defined the type in the header,

```
typedef struct MyAUGraphPlayer {
    AUGraph graph;
    AudioUnit speechAU;
 } MyAUGraphPlayer;
```

and declared it in the .m,

```
@implementation SpeechGraph {
    MyAUGraphPlayer player;
}
```

However when trying to initialize it, I get the error `Unexpected expression' from this code (the error is on the line player = ...)

```
- (void)setup { 
   player = { 0 };
   CreateMyAUGraph(&player);
}
```

The player variable is recognized as a MyAUGraph type but doing the conventional { 0 } assignment leads to a compile-time error.

I have built this Core-Audio code fine in a command line project but now I'm attempting to build a UI around it and apparently some of the mixing between the C core stuff and object oriented stuff is causing some confusion for me.  I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `player` is not a global variable. It is an instance variable (ivar) of `SpeechGraph`.

Second: In modern Objective-C, instance variables are initialized to 0 in newly `alloc`ed objects, by default. There is no need to set this value to 0 again. See [Programming With Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW7), "Working with Objects", "Objects Are Created Dynamically".

Third: If you really need to set the value, `player = (MyAUGraphPlayer) { 0 };` should work. (This is an assignment, not an initialization. [More about the difference.](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/assignment-and-initialization/))

Comment: `player = (MyAUGraphPlayer) { 0 }` is an assignment and not initialisation, but never mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can only initialise a variable when you first declare it. By the time your method gets called it’s already to late for initialisation.

What you are trying to do here is interpreted as an assignment by the compiler (only a `=` after the declaration is an initialisation!) – and the right hand value is a block here. This is what leads to a compiler error.

You’ll have to do it by hand (or not all).

Comment: that gets the same error.  What is weird is i could easily say `MyAUGraphPlayer player = { 0 }' in a function and its fine but simply trying to make that play a globally declared constant leads to this error.

Comment: @AlexanderBollbach Sorry, I didn’t think properly about your problem. Answer updated...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only initialize a struct that way when declaring it.

> MyAUGraphPlayer player = { 0 };

In your case you should use memset like this.

> memset(&player,0,sizeof(MyAUGraphPlayer));

Comment: is memset necessary?  I recall something about structs having all their fields 'zeroed' out if they are declared locally and not zeroed out if they are a class member variable?  If that is the case than memset is called for, no?

Comment: I think objective c objects' ivars have all of their bits zeroed out when they're initialized.  Local variables definitely do not.  I personally just initialize everything all the time either way, just to be safe.